# Combine dictionaries in recursive function?

Tags: .net, dictionary, recursion, type-conversion

I've got a function that is supposed to recursively loop through a control and it's children and return any form values within that control (textboxes, checkboxes, radiobuttons) and spit that out as a dictionary where the key is the control id and the value is the text or value of the control.

However I am running into an issue on the line where the recursion happens, it gives me the following error:

> `Unable to cast object of type '<UnionIterator>d__88`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'.`

Code:

```
Public Shared Function getFormValuesInsideControl(ByVal control As Control) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim formValues As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    If control IsNot Nothing Then
        If control.HasControls = True Then
            For Each childControl As Control In control.Controls
                formValues = formValues.Union(getFormValuesInsideControl(childControl)) 'error happens here'
            Next
        Else
            Select Case TypeName(control)
                Case "TextBox"
                    Dim textbox As TextBox = control
                    formValues.Add(formatControlName(textbox.ID), textbox.Text)
                Case "CheckBox"
                    Dim checkbox As CheckBox = control
                    If checkbox.Checked = True Then
                        formValues.Add(formatControlName(checkbox.ID), "Yes")
                    End If
                Case "RadioButton"
                    Dim radioButton As RadioButton = control
                    If radioButton.Checked = True Then
                        formValues.Add(formatControlName(radioButton.ID), "Yes")
                    End If
            End Select
        End If

    End If

    Return formValues
End Function
```

I see what is happening but I am not sure why or how to fix it.

How can I combine these dictionaries in this line? I've seen examples of doing that in LINQ, but I don't think I can do that here due to the recursive aspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `Union` is returning an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<x,y>>` rather than an actual `Dictionary<x,y>`

to fix it you could do this:

```
     formValues.Union(getFormValuesInsideControl(childControl)).ToDictionary(function (x) x.Key, function (x) x.Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
formValues = formValues.Union(getFormValuesInsideControl(childControl)).ToDictionary(Function(o) o.Key, Function(o) o.Value)
```